# If $a_sk^s+a_{s-1}k^{s-1}+...+a_0$ is the basis representation of $n$ with respect to the basis $k$. Then, $0<n\leq k^{s+1}-1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation

If $a_sk^s+a_{s-1}k^{s-1}+...+a_0$ is the basis representation of $n$ with respect to the basis $k$. Then, $$0<n\leq k^{s+1}-1$$.

**My attempt:-**
By basis represantation, we know that $0\leq a_j<k,j=0,1,2,3,...,s.$

$a_sk^s+a_{s-1}k^{s-1}+...+a_0<k.k^s+k.k^{s-1}+...+k=k(k^s+k^{s-1}+...+1)=k.\frac{k^{s+1}-1}{k-1}.$

I am not able to reduce further. Since $\frac{k}{k-1}>1$. Please help me.

**Another attempt:-**
$a_sk^s+a_{s-1}k^{s-1}+...+a_0<k.k^s+k.k^{s-1}+...+k<k^{s+1}+k^s+...+k+1=\frac{k^{s+2}-1}{k-1}.$

Comment: As written, this isn't true, as it excludes the numbers with all digits equal to $k-1$, such as $999$ in base $10$. You want to prove either $n < k^{s+1}$ or $n \leq k^{s+1} - 1$.

Comment: sorry, I corrected the question. Thank you.

Comment: **TeX:** For ellipsis, it's better to use `\dots` (or `\ldots`, etc.) instead of `...` (note the difference in spacing: `a+b+\ldots+c` $\color{blue}{a+b+\ldots+c}$ vs. `a+b+...+c` $\color{blue}{a+b+...+c}$). For multiplication, `\cdot` $\color{blue}{\cdot}$ or `\times` $\color{blue}{\times}$ is a better choice than the plain dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with both of your attempts is that your inequalities are not precise enough. Instead, with $n \ge 0$ (note $n = 0$ can also be represented with $s = 0$ and $a_0 = 0$) in base $k$, for some $s \geq 0$ we have

$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{s}a_i k^i, \; \; 0 \le a_i \le k - 1 \; \forall \; 0 \le i \le s$$

Thus, $n$ must be less than or equal to the maximum possible value with those limits on the digits, i.e., where $a_i = k - 1$ for all $0 \le i \le s$. This then gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n & \le \sum_{i=0}^{s}(k-1) k^i \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{s}(k^{i+1}-k^i) \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{s}k^{i+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{s}k^i \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{s+1}k^{i} - \sum_{i=0}^{s}k^i \\
& = \left(k^{s+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{s}k^{i}\right) - \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{s}k^i\right) \\
& = k^{s+1} - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$